# JW6 changing the state of a dock icon

Tags: jquery, css, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I have 2 icons on my dock, thumbs up and thumbs down. When I click on the thumbs up icon, I want the icon to have a different background so that the user will know that the icon was clicked. I have the button and buttonActive elements on my skin.

```
<elements>
    <element name="divider" src="..."/>
    <element name="button" src="..."/>
    <element name="buttonActive" src="..."/>
</elements>
```

I want to trigger the active state of the element once the button is clicked.

I created the button as follows

```
player.addButton("http://rocketscience.is/img/thumbs_up.png", "Thumbs Up", function(something) { 
    console.log(this);
}, "firstButton" );
```

When I checked the value of this, it holds a map with the buttons in the dock and their corresponding functions. Is there a way to get the button object when the button is clicked? I know it can be done by figuring out the id (pattern of how it is being generated) of the button and doing a `$(id)`, but I was wondering if there was a different way to do the same.

Comment: Where have you tried running this?

Comment: This is on my local machine

Comment: Can you put something up?